# couchbase maintainence convenience compare mysql

Tags: couchbase

I am using nodejs and couchbase to develop web app.
Just wonder if couchbase maintainence is easy and convenient compare to mysql?

Your comment welcome

Comment: What dou you mean under "maintenance"?

Comment: Are you referring to hardware or tasks such as creating indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the administration and scaling of Couchbase is very simple. I'd say setup of mysql is also relatively simple as well but there is more work in optimizing indexes, and the development process is more involved, you have to do CREATE/ALTER table and migrations for every change, taking mysql down for each change.

When it comes to scaling horizontally, **Couchbase beats MySQL hands** down for ease of scaling. Deciding on your mysql strategy is challenging, replication is slow and still suffers from not being able to scale the master. Sharding is equally as complex.

If you have a small application and don't need to optimize queries or anything and a single server is sufficient for your database, then you are only really changing your development process. The differences in this scenario are smaller.